# How do I create an array of items after outputting them all individually to the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

As you can see at the moment the result of the code is outputting each value of the options list to the console. However I want them to be grouped into an array variable rather than the code outputting it one by one. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```js
(function($){
   $('.request-poc').attr('href', function() {
      var product = $(this).attr("data-product");
      return this.href + '?product=' + product;
   });
   if ($('body.request-poc').length > 0)
   {
      function GetURLParameter(sParam)
      {
         var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
         var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
         for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
         {
               var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
               if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
               return sParameterName[1];
            }
         }
      }
      var product = GetURLParameter('product');
      console.log(product)
      $('#product').val(product);
   }

   Array.from(document.querySelector("#product").options).forEach(function(option_element) {
      let option_value = option_element.value;
      console.log(option_value);
  }); 

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='request-poc'>

    <h1>Dummy</h1>

    <form action="#">
        <select name="Select product" id="product">
            <option value="SHOES">Shoes</option>
            <option value="SHIRT">Shirt</option>
            <option value="JUMPER">Jumper</option>
            <option value="SOCKS">Socks</option>
            <option value="JEANS">Jeans</option>
            <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with the console. That's just a distraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare an empty array and push all the options in it.

```js
(function ($) {
  $(".request-poc").attr("href", function () {
    var product = $(this).attr("data-product");
    return this.href + "?product=" + product;
  });

  if ($("body.request-poc").length > 0) {
    function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
      var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split("&");
      for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split("=");
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
          return sParameterName[1];
        }
      }
    }
    var product = GetURLParameter("product");
    console.log(product);
    $("#product").val(product);
  }

  const arr = [];
  Array.from(document.querySelector("#product").options).forEach(function (
    option_element
  ) {
    arr.push(option_element.value);
  });
  console.log(arr);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='request-poc'>

    <h1>Dummy</h1>

    <form action="#">
        <select name="Select product" id="product">
            <option value="SHOES">Shoes</option>
            <option value="SHIRT">Shirt</option>
            <option value="JUMPER">Jumper</option>
            <option value="SOCKS">Socks</option>
            <option value="JEANS">Jeans</option>
            <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the help! Works exactly as intended. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could you set an empty array outside your foreach loop then push to it in the loop

example would be (not tested)

```
var test =[]   
Array.from(document.querySelector("#product").options).forEach(function(option_element) {
      let option_value = option_element.value;
      console.log(option_value);
      test.push(option_value)
  });
```